# Building Tree Structure from a list of string paths

Tags: python, tree

I have a list of paths as in

```
paths = ["x1/x2", "x1/x2/x3", "x1/x4", "x1/x5/x6", ...]
```

where the actual length of the list if roughly 20,000. I want to construct a tree structure that can be printed. The tree structure would look something like this:

```
x1
├── x2
│   └── x3
├── x4
└── x5
    └── x6
```

I also want to have some data associated to each node in the Node Object that can be currently accessed through a dictionary where each node is a key e.g.

```
d = {"x1": [[1,2], [3,4]], "x2": [[5,6], [7,8]], ...}
```

Every tree node should inherit the data from its parent. Such that the data at the "x2" node would be `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]`.

I have tried the module `anytree` but it requires that you define each node of the tree as a variable. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it would help if you show how the "tree" appears when printed.

Comment: Edited the post showing tree structure now.

Comment: I've changed my solution. It might save you a lot of if-else if you specify a root. I assume that `x1` is the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one possible solution might be like this.

The tree nodes store their parents in order to construct the messy `├───`
and `└───` before directory/file names.

Output:

```
x1
├── x2
│   └── x3
├── x4
└── x5
    └── x6
```

Code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)
        return node

    def print(self, is_root):
        pre_0 = "    "
        pre_1 = "│   "
        pre_2 = "├── "
        pre_3 = "└── "

        tree = self
        prefix = pre_2 if tree.parent and id(tree) != id(tree.parent.children[-1]) else pre_3

        while tree.parent and tree.parent.parent:
            if tree.parent.parent and id(tree.parent) != id(tree.parent.parent.children[-1]):
                prefix = pre_1 + prefix
            else:
                prefix = pre_0 + prefix

            tree = tree.parent

        if is_root:
            print(self.name)
        else:
            print(prefix + self.name)

        for child in self.children:
            child.print(False)

def find_and_insert(parent, edges):
    # Terminate if there is no edge
    if not edges:
        return
    
    # Find a child with the name edges[0] in the current node
    match = [tree for tree in parent.children if tree.name == edges[0]]
    
    # If there is already a node with the name edges[0] in the children, set "pointer" tree to this node. If there is no such node, add a node in the current tree node then set "pointer" tree to it
    tree = match[0] if match else parent.add_child(TreeNode(edges[0], parent))
    
    # Recursively process the following edges[1:]
    find_and_insert(tree, edges[1:])

paths = ["x1/x2", "x1/x2/x3", "x1/x4", "x1/x5/x6"]

root = TreeNode("x1", None)

for path in paths:
    find_and_insert(root, path.split("/")[1:])

root.print(True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please give a bit of an explanation for the find_and_insert() function? I am trying to implement some data in each node that is inherit from the parent (see last edit) with your class..

Comment: @CosmicPeanutButter I added some comments. Basically `find_and_insert(parent, list_of_names)` tracks down the `list_of_names` from the tree node `parent`, and inserts a new node at the appropriate location if necessary.

Comment: @CosmicPeanutButter I forgot to mention. Since the tree has its parent stored, you can traverse upwards to get the associated data in each node.

Answer (score 0):

[`bigtree`](https://bigtree.readthedocs.io) is a Python tree implementation that integrates with Python lists, dictionaries, and pandas DataFrame.

For this scenario, there are three parts to this,

1. Define a new Node class that does the inheritance of data from parent nodes
2. Construct tree using the path list and Node class we defined earlier (1 line of code!)
3. Add in the data dictionary that maps the node name to data (1 line of code!)

```
from bigtree import Node, list_to_tree, print_tree, add_dict_to_tree_by_name

# Define new Node class
class NodeInherit(Node):
    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.is_root:
            return self._data
        return self.parent.data + self._data

# Construct tree using the path list
paths = ["x1/x2", "x1/x2/x3", "x1/x4", "x1/x5/x6"]
root = list_to_tree(paths, node_type=NodeInherit)

# Add in the data dictionary
d = {"x1": [[1,2], [3,4]], "x2": [[5,6], [7,8]], "x3": [[9]], "x4": [[5,6]], "x5": [[5]], "x6": [[6]]}
d2 = {k: {"_data": v} for k, v in d.items()}  # minor input format change
root = add_dict_to_tree_by_name(root, d2)

# Check tree structure with data
print_tree(root, attr_list=["data"])
```

This results in output,

```
x1 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
├── x2 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]]
│   └── x3 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]]
├── x4 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]
└── x5 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]]
    └── x6 [data=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6]]]
```

You can also export the data out to dictionary or pandas DataFrame format besides printing it out to console.

Source/Disclaimer: I'm the creator of [`bigtree`](https://bigtree.readthedocs.io) ;)