# Get the string directory structure representation, given a list of string file paths in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, treeview

Given a List of Strings to each file within the structure

```
var paths = new List<string> {"root_folder/a first folder/holidays.mov", "root_folder/a first folder/javascript-file.js", etc...}
```

I need to output a String that represents the directory structure

```
root_folder/
|-- a first folder/
|   |-- holidays.mov
|   |-- javascript-file.js
|   `-- some_picture.jpg
|-- documents/
|   |-- spreadsheet.xls
|   |-- manual.pdf
|   |-- document.docx
|   `-- presentation.ppt
|       `-- test    
|-- empty_folder/
|-- going deeper/
|   |-- going deeper/
|   |   `-- going deeper/
|   |        `-- going deeper/
|   |            `-- .secret_file
|   |-- style.css
|   `-- index.html
|-- music and movies/
|   |-- great-song.mp3
|   |-- S01E02.new.episode.avi
|   |-- S01E02.new.episode.nfo
|   `-- track 1.cda
|-- .gitignore
|-- .htaccess
|-- .npmignore
|-- archive 1.zip
|-- archive 2.tar.gz
|-- logo.svg
`-- README.md
```

I found some information for the [TreeView control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c253e3e8-420b-4bb9-813c-a3951df3a581/populate-treeview-from-string-array?forum=csharpgeneral) but I just need to output a String.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the directory structure with this class I've made:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder
/// </summary>
public class CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder Parent { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
    public bool Write { get; set; }
    public List<CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder> Children { get; private set; }

    public CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder(string name, CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder parent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
        Children = new List<CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder>();
    }

    public bool Contains(string name)
    {
        return Children.Any(d => d.Name.Equals(name));
    }

    public CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder Get(string name)
    {
        return Children.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.Equals(name));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void PrintTree(StringBuilder output, bool isRoot)
    {
        string prefix;
        string pre_0 = "    ";
        string pre_1 = "│   ";
        string pre_2 = "|-- ";
        string pre_3 = "`-- ";

        CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder tree = this;

        if (tree.Parent != null && !(tree.Equals(tree.Parent.Children.Last())))
        {
            prefix = pre_2;
        }
        else
        {
            prefix = pre_3;
        }

        while (tree.Parent != null && tree.Parent.Parent != null)
        {
            if (tree.Parent != null && !(tree.Parent.Equals(tree.Parent.Parent.Children.Last())))
            {
                prefix = pre_1 + prefix;
            }
            else
            {
                prefix = pre_0 + prefix;
            }

            tree = tree.Parent;
        }

        if (isRoot)
        {
            output.AppendLine(this.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            output.AppendLine(prefix + this.Name);
        }

        foreach (CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder child in this.Children)
        {
            child.PrintTree(output, false);
        }
    }
    public static void TreeStruct(CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder parent, List<string> edges)
    {
        if (edges.Count == 0) return;


        List<CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder> matchedChildren = new List<CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder>();

        foreach (CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder tree in parent.Children)
        {
            if (tree.Name == edges[0])
            {
                matchedChildren.Add(tree);
            }
        }

        CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder pointer;

        if (matchedChildren.Count != 0)
        {
            pointer = matchedChildren[0];
        }
        else
        {
            pointer = new CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder(edges[0], parent);
            parent.Children.Add(pointer);
        }

        edges.RemoveAt(0);
        TreeStruct(pointer, edges);
    }

}
```

To use simply declare a `CodeComparisonToolDirBuilder` at the root folder/node. This was inspired by [Building Tree Structure from a list of string paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994282/building-tree-structure-from-a-list-of-string-paths)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a treeview is kind of ideal, since you can then provide a windows like explorer view, and do so in a web page. the result is a VERY nice interface.

However, you can also use the windows command line, and use the "tree" command, and it will output files and a tree like structure.

So, say this:

[image]

So, you can use shell() command, and capture the output of the windows command "tree", and it does quite a nice job.

It really depends on what you want to do with the final output.

Overall, it not a whole lot less code to use a treeview, since as such, they can be recursive.

Comment: Yes I understand but for my web application usage of the terminal isn't allowed. Additionally i'm creating a directory diff checker tool and a Treeview isn't what I need to pass to my diffing algorithm.

Comment: Ok, shell() is a bit lame anyway. I'll dig up some code - I'm sure I have a dir walker in VB.net - I'll dig that up, and post as c# - so still not too hard and possible solutions exist